# Bad Message (Cannot access the directory)

Tags: command-line, bash, arch-linux, file-corruption, manjaro

I used the cmd `cd .themes`

It shows:

```
bash: cd: .themes: Bad message
```

Because of this I cannot access my $Home directory from regular file manager. I am using Manjaro xfce distribution and I'm still a beginner.

And also whenever I used the cmd`ls -al` it shows:

```
ls: cannot access '.themes': Bad message
d?????????  ? ?         ?             ?            ? .themes
```

Because of this problem I'm unable to access other directories in my $Home directory. How can I get rid of this?

I have tried to move the .themes directory away by issuing in the $HOME directory: `mv .themes /tmp/corrupt_dir`
but it shows:

```
mv: cannot stat '.themes': Bad message
```

Comment: First, you must check out [file system integrity](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bad-message-cannot-access-the-directory/143595/4), so create bootable Linux USB drive and boot your machine with one to run as *root user* the cmd **[fsck -a /dev/sdXX](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fsck)**.

Answer (score 4):

Unmount the disk and try in root terminal e2fsck /dev/(drivename)

**tldr** e2fsck

**e2fsck**

Check a Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. The filesystem should be unmounted at the time the command is run.
More information: https://manned.org/e2fsck.

- Check filesystem, reporting any damaged blocks:
  e2fsck /dev/sdXN
- Check filesystem and automatically repair any damaged blocks:
  e2fsck -p /dev/sdXN
- Check filesystem in read only mode:
  e2fsck -c /dev/sdXN